# Extract and combine different values from table and make new variables (for histogram)

Tags: matlab

I have a 4x15 table (4 participants and 15 variables). I want to make histograms (or plots)for all the participants individually.
For one variable (x-axis), I want to combine three values that are not individual variables (3 of the 15), they are all Reaction times from different trials.
For the other variable (y-axis), I also want to combine what in the table now are three different variables into one variable with three expressions (values).

So the question is how I can extract 3 cells values (say from the first row for the first participants), and combine them into 3 values of one variable. And then do the same for the other variable, which i want to plot in the last step.

I tried the following already (but does not seem to work):

LNBtableS1 is the name of the 4x15 table
LNB_TP0, LNB_TP1, etc are the variable names

```
%assign values from cells (same row) to new variable (one variable with different expressions/values
%how to extract specific values from table and combine them into new variable with three expression /datapoints? 

x = (1:1,[LNB_TP0 LNB_TP1 LNB_TP2])% first row = first participant 

x1 = LNBtableS1.LNB_TP0  (1:1,[LNB_TP0])
x2 = LNBtableS1.LNB_TP1  (1:1,[LNB_TP1])
x3 = LNBtableS1.LNB_TP2  (1:1,[LNB_TP2])
 
y= (1:1,[LNB_RTC0 LNB_RCT1 LNB_RCT2])

y1 =  LNBtableS1.LNB_RTC0  (1:1,[LNB_RTC0])
y2 =  LNBtableS1.LNB_RTC1  (1:1,[LNB_RTC1])
y3 =  LNBtableS1.LNB_RTC2  (1:1,[LNB_RTC2])

%plot or make histogram from x and y
```

I also tried this to make a new table with two variables and the corresponding values, which also does not seem to work

```
TG = newtable([LNB_TP0; LNB_TP1; LNB_TP2],[LNB_RTC0;LNB_RTC1;LNB_RTC2], 
    'VariableNames',{'TP','RT'})
TG = newtable([LNBtableS1(1:1,  {'LNB_TP0', 'LNB_TP1', 'LNB_TP2'})],[LNBtableS1(1:1,  {'LNB_RTC0', 'LNB_RTC1', 'LNB_RTC2'})], 
    'VariableNames',{'TP','RT'})
TG = newtable([LNBtableS1(1:1,[19 22 25])],[LNBtableS1(1:1,[21 24 27])],  'VariableNames',{'TP','RT'})
```

Neither does it work to create new variables like this (which I can then combine in a plot or histo):

```
Try with dataset 

%create new variable with cells values from table 
TP =  LNBtableS1(1:1,  {'LNB_TP0', 'LNB_TP1', 'LNB_TP2'})
RT =  LNBtableS1(1:1,  {'LNB_RTC0', 'LNB_RTC1', 'LNB_RTC2'})

%create indexing? -> doesn't work 
TP = LNBtableS1(1:1,  {'LNB_TP0' 1; 'LNB_TP1' 2; 'LNB_TP2' 3});
RT = LNBtableS1(1:1, {'LNB_RTC0' 1; 'LNB_RTC1' 2; 'LNB_RTC2' 3})

%make into dataset
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have a 4x15 table (4 participants and 15 variables); variables include (among others) RT (reaction time) from three different conditions.  Now, I want to combine the three different values for reaction time (from the table) for one participant into a new variable with three expressions. As in RT in milli sec as new variable x = [32 33 31], with the three values 32, 33, 31. The problem is that I don`t know how to extract the single values (cells) from the table to combine them to a new variable.   All help is highly appreciated!